# Numerical Derivative ND doesn't work

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, contexts

I have entered the following code from the [`ND` documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/NumericalCalculus/ref/ND.html), and get the wrong answer.

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];
ND[Exp[x],x,1]
(*--> 0. *)
```

(The correct answer should be $e^1=2.71828$.) When I hover over `ND`, I get a warning saying "ND occurs in more than one context". However, it seems like `NumericalCalculus` is first in the context path, and therefore I am indeed using the `ND` defined in the `NumericalCalculus` package.

```
$ContextPath
(*--->{NumericalCalculus`,SVTools`,DocumentationSearch`,ResourceLocator`,URLUtilities`,PacletManager`,System`,Global`})

Context[ND]
(*---> NumericalCalculus`)
```

So what the heck is going on?

Comment: Evaluating your code with a clean notebook in a new V12.0 session running on Mac OS 10.13, I get the expected answer. I can only conclude there is something has been corrupted in your Mathematica session.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I can not reproduce the problem the OP is experiencing; I suspect it is being caused by corrupted lexical elements in the OP's Mathematica notebook.

Comment: @m_goldberg Well, to be honest that's an alright answer already. At least I understand the nature of my problem a little better now.